# The least number of distinct averages

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a set of $n$ distinct real numbers where $a_i\in[0,1]$ for each $a_i$ in $A$. $F(A)$ is the set of averages of all pairs in $A$. $f_n$ is the minimal possible value of $|F(A)|$ where $|A|=n$. So how do I get the seqeuence $\{f_n\}$?

Example: For $A_4=\{0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1 \}$, $F(A_4)=\{\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6}\}$ which happens to contain the least number of members for all four-element $A$, so $f_4=5$.

My guess is that when $A$ contains $n$ equidistant points, $F(A)$ has the least number of members, because this way $|F(A)|$ grows linearly with $|A|$, but I can't establish a proof.

Comment: Might as well deal with sums of pairs instead of averages. I think it's well-known that the minimal case is numbers in arithmetic progression (or, as you put it, equidistant points) but I'd have to search to find a reference.

Comment: But I would suggest doing a websearch for $$\rm arithemetic\ progression\ sumset$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a grid on the $x,y$ plane with $(x,y)=(a_j,a_k)$, then you are counting the number of diagonal lines $x+y=2s$ that you have to draw so as to catch all the 2d points, i.e. the number of distinct values of $s$ that you need for that. A line with a given $s$ will intercept most points, when they are evenly spaced, and in that case you need $2n-1$ values, counting all: in your calculation instead you left out the values $0$ and $1$.